# Best way to use CRUD for a custom module in the frontend

Tags: magento-1.9, module, php-5.4, customer-account

I want to know the best way to implement CRUD for a custom module in the front end.Basically there is new and edit custom form in the front end.The user's input is stored in the database created with the module and operations are carried out in the controller and custom blocks to meet the requirements of CRUD.So operations are performed using ID's to know which row in the database is to be updated or deleted.

Everything is custom made i.e. a custom model is being used for storing the data read from the front end using a custom form.And all operations are done using custom controllers,helpers,layout etc.The data that I am working with is customers data read from the form and form is present in the my account section for logged in customers.I am also using update handle="customer_account" for the layouts.

So I basically want to learn how to implement CRUD efficiently in magento for something like this.

Comment: What kind of data are you working with? Does it already exist as part of Magento or is it a custom model? Is this for any site user to be able to do or is it authenticated? There's a pretty broad scope here. You should narrow down what  you're looking for as this potentially is answered by a simply searching for "magento crud" in your favorite engine.

Comment: @pspahn I have updated the question.